# Custom webpack error during update angular from 11 to 12

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, webpack

I'm trying to update my angular version from 11.1.1 to 12.1.1. That I'm getting this build error.

> "CustomWebpackDevServerSchema" schema is using the keyword "id" which its support is deprecated. Use "$id" for schema ID.
>
> "BuildCustomWebpackBrowserSchema" schema is using the keyword "id" which its support is deprecated. Use "$id" for schema ID.

- angular version: 12.1.1
- @angular-builders/custom-webpack: 11.1.1

I tried removing `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` and install again, but not working.

I did not find any similar questions.

Comment: I believe you should update custom webpack version to latest one

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if you got an answer for this?
But here's a possible solution.

In our project the issue was because we use cusom webpack config for tailwind.  A solution for this issue, is to ensure the package `"@angular-builders/custom-webpack` is the same version as your angular core. If your are using angular core 12, then install `"@angular-builders/custom-webpack@12`:

```
npm i -D @angular-builders/custom-webpack@12
```